# Helm upgrade failed error rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

After installing 2 releases of the same chart (but different release name) in the same namespace I get the following error:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with update: ConfigMap "green-script" in namespace "x" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal "blue-x": current value is "green-x"
```

I don't want this helm release to take control over the resources of the second release (which btw, have different labels and annotations).

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: green-x
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: x
  creationTimestamp: "2021-10-25T09:30:02Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: x
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: green-x
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 6.1.1
    helm.sh/chart: x-0.1.10
  name: green-script
  namespace: x
```

Is there a way where I can tell helm not to import resources or import resources according to a specific annotation?

Comment: Usually the way to fix this is to make sure every object's name includes `{{ .Release.Name }}`, maybe using a helper template.  Can you edit the question to include the template code that generates this specific object?

Comment: Hi facing the same issue. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @DavidMaze Can you please tell me where do we need to add {{ .Release.Name }} because we have already added annotations: meta.helm.sh/release-name: <shdbj>

Comment: @ParthVerma do you get any solution?

Comment: @sush i had resolved this by updating the release once installed. Installing an already installed release was giving me this error. try upgrading after installing, or delete the chart first and then install. let me know if this works